# How to show that $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\Gamma^{{k-1\over n+1}}(n+x)=\Gamma(x)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+x)^{{1\over k^n}}?$

Tags: infinite-product

Let

$$P=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\Gamma^{{k-1\over n+1}}(n+x)$$

$$Q=\Gamma(x)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+x)^{{1\over k^n}}$$

$x\ge1$ and $k>1$

Where $\Gamma(n)$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

**How do we show that $P=Q?$**

I haven't even got a clue where to begin.

I believe I got the idea of the products $P$ and $Q$ from observing [Knar's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnarsFormula.html).

It is quite long ago, so there is no other hints I could added to help.

Comment: Log differentiation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation

Comment: For $k=2,x=1$, I seem to get $Q = 2.7612$ and $P = +\infty$.